# Как совместить код?

Tags: контроль-версий, dvcs

Я и мой товарищ пишем 1 программу, и приходится ее после совмещать вручную, можно ли как то это сделать автоматически? Как внести изменения ?

Comment: Как насчёт использовать систему контроля версий?

Comment: А чем плох Subversion?

Comment: @SVD102 SVN является системой контроля версий (VCS), но не является распределённой системой контроля версий (DVCS). С ним вы обязаны иметь сервер и жестко к нему привязаны. Если сервер недоступен, сохранить код не получится.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Спасибо. Все бы такие комментарии давали, четко по делу, а не пижонились как некоторые тут...

Comment: @SVD102 спасибо, стараюсь подавать хороший пример)

Comment: @SVD102 прочитали рекомендуемые вопросы?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Да прочитал. Уже всё освоил. Выбрал Git. Меня все устраивает.

Comment: @SVD102 год прошел. Как ваши успехи? Что с этой программой - написали?

Answer (score 7):

Вам нужна система контроля версий. В комментариях совершенно справедливо предлагают две наиболее современных и популярных: Git и Mercurial. Лично я предпочитаю и люблю Git, но это субъективно.

В общем и целом процесс будет организован так:

- Локальный репозиторий у каждого из вас на рабочей машине
- Удаленный репозиторий - новичку проще всего использовать хостинг GitHub или Bitbucket.
- У каждого разработчика своя ветка, куда вы вносите изменения.
- Есть центральная ветка, в которую эти изменения периодически добавляются.
- При добавлении изменений неизбежно будут конфликты, которые вам придётся разрешать.

Вне зависимости от вашего выбора:

- Прочитайте документацию, хотя бы новичковый курс. Продолжайте читать документацию впоследствии до постижения Дао выбранной системы.
- Для старта пройдите какой-нибудь онлайн-курс, их много и все вполне хороши. (Платный брать нет смысла)
- При появлении вопросов приходите на Ru.SO.
- Сливайте изменения в центральную ветку как можно чаще, чтобы избежать адских страданий, неразрешимых конфликтов и поножовщины (см. ниже про непрерывную интеграцию).

Связанные вопросы, рекомендуемые к прочтению:

- [Организация GIT для небольшой команды разработчиков.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/409050/181472)
- [Git для программиста-одиночки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424882/181472)
- [Количество, частота и содержание коммитов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/356209/181472)
- [Как организовать работу с системами контроля версий для разработки нескольких проектов с общей основой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478100/181472)
- [Что такое непрерывная интеграция?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/470453/181472)

Про Hg не нашёл подходящих, добавляйте.